# как убрать спецсимволы из строковой переменной в golang

Tags: golang

неожиданно возник такой вопрос.

```
s := `абв \n мой текст здесь \n`
fmt.Print(s)
```

---

на выходе я получаю  "абв \n мой текст здесь \n", а хотелось бы получить:

абв

мой текст здесь

Более конкретно, я, видимо, ищу функцию, которая примет строку в обратных одиночных кавычках, а вернёт в двойных.

Comment: `s := "абв \nмой текст здесь \n"
 fmt.Println(s)`
Go Playground - https://play.golang.org/p/iok_mnTlcE

Comment: @matz Думаю, ОП имеет в виду ситацию, когда строка приходит откуда-то снаружи программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если строка ваша - то просто пишите в двойных кавычках:

```
s := "абв \n мой текст здесь \n"
```

Если же вы получаете строку откуда-то, то можете использовать [`strconv.Unquote`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) вот таким образом:

```
s, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + s + `"`)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/bH4UaFTo73.